# Apache proxy for multiple websites

Tags: apache, virtualhost, web-hosting

I am attempting to use a remote Apache client (10.0.0.1) as a proxy, that forwards all requests to the backend Apache server (10.0.0.2) that hosts multiple different sites.
How can I get the proxy client to forward all requests with the proper domain?

My current config on the proxy is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    <Proxy balancer://backendservers>
        BalancerMember http://10.0.0.2
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / balancer://backendservers/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://backendservers/
</VirtualHost>
```

The issue that I am facing is that all requests lose the proper domain header. How can I set the domain header dynamically so I do not have the have a virtualhost for every site hosted on the backend server?

Comment: Is there only one backend server?  If so, why are you using "balancer" as opposed to a regular reverse proxy?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I added the load balancer because I may add a second web server in the near future.